# Move icons underneath h2 heading?

Tags: html, css

[image]For some reason I cant seem to figure out how to move my social media icons to be underneath the social media h2 heading. I want them to display horizontally instead of vertically as well. Any help?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="footer-section social media col-md-3">
  <h2>Social Media</h2>
  <div class="social-media">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.social-media {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .social-media > li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to align them horizontally under the header

```css
.list-unstyled {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
/*
  Add a bit of margin at the left side of each icon, except for the first one 
*/
li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="footer-section social media col-md-3">
  <h2>Social Media</h2>
  <div class="social-media">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for that. I removed the div with social-media, it's undessesary.

```css
.social-media {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-media > li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="footer-section social media col-md-3">
  <h2>Social Media</h2>
    <ul class="social-media">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using bootstrap 4. Class `media` in `.footer-section` made this block to act like `flex` box. Removed class `media` So the child elements was looked inline. Is this the result you was looking for?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer-section social col-md-3">
  <h2 class="col">Social Media</h2>
  <div class="social-media">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bare minimum code for your problem; just the basics. You can adjust the following code to your liking.

```
h2 { margin-bottom: 0; } // Remove Space from underneath h2

.list-unstyled { // Remove Bullet Points and Space Around List
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li { display: inline-block; } // Make your list items display horizontally.
```